# search logs for events associated with Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, windows-event-log, task-scheduler, logparser

I'm working with a Server08 box (Web Edition) where the Task Scheduler had run a set of unchanged housekeeping scripts for months. Over the last week, Scheduler has failed to start scripts twice.

TS's UI is not reporting any error condition - just doesn't run the scripts. I'd like to run a query (either PowerShell or Log Parser) to pull any TS-based events for the last week but i'm not sure of the best approach, syntax, or process names to look for.

thx

Answer (score 0):

Why not look at the Task Scheduler log?

Comment: The one that lists actions by task? I haven't found any errors there - it merely lists that the given task completed sucessfully. Something interrupting the engine itself...not the task itself.

Comment: When you look at the task history, what is the operational code?

Comment: in the 'last run result' The operation completed successfully. (0x0) in the History event 102 | Task Completed | (2)